# Addition of numbers from string delimited by ' . '

Tags: c, string

I want to write a C program which will take an IP address from the user like `"112.234.456.789"` in a string and give formatted output in addition of each block in string, e.g., `"04.09.15.24"` for the above IP address. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    char s[15],d[11];
    int i=0,c = 0, sum[4] = {0};

    d[i]=sum[c]/10;
    printf("Enter ip address:");
    gets(s);
    printf("\n \n %s",s);
    i=0;
    for(c=0;c<15;c++)
    {
        if(s[c]!='.'||s[c]!='\0')
            sum[i]=(s[c]-48)+sum[i];
        else
            i++;
    }

    for(i=0,c=0;c<4;c++,i+=3)
    {
        d[i]=(sum[c]/10)+48;
        d[i+1]=sum[c]%10+48;
        d[i+2]='.';
    }
    printf("\n \n %s",d);
    getch();
}
```

The input should be an IP address like `"112.234.546.234"`, and the output should be the result of adding the digits in each block, `"04.09.15.06"`. The input and output should be in strings.

Comment: Please provide an example of your input and the expected output.

Comment: @DaniloPiazzalunga, the OP has.

Comment: Also, use real variable names please.  Fortran77 style vars hurts my brain.

Comment: input should be ip addr like 112.234.546.234
and output should be addn of each blocks 04.09.15.06
input and output should be in string.

Comment: I presume you realize each number in an IP address cannot be greater than 255 (IPv4, anyway)? Doesn't really affect what you're trying to do, but it does make your examples a bit invalid...

Comment: sry sry....but the main task is to addition of each block of digits and storing it again in another string.

Comment: Well, it is not clear whether the input is an IP address or just a series of dotted decimals. Then I am not sure I can understand the example, nor the requirement: should the output be the sum of the dotted decimals (e.g. 112+234+546+234 for `112.234.546.234`) or should it be the IP address as a 32-bit number?

Comment: 1+1+2.2+3+4.5+4+6.2+3+4  here the addition is specified by .

Comment: the input and output should be in string

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that `s[c]!='.'||s[c]!='\0'` is going to evaluate true for *any* character in the input -- even `'.'`. This means `i` is never incremented, and ot only is every digit is summed to `sum[0]`, but so is `'.' - 48`.

What you meant was `s[c] != '.' && s[c] != '\0'`.

I wrote the function you desire [here](http://ideone.com/mXYNa).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void convert(const char *in, char *out) {
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  char ch;
  do {
    ch = *in++;
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      sum += ch - '0';
    } else {
      *out++ = sum / 10 + '0';
      *out++ = sum % 10 + '0';
      if (ch == '.') {
        *out++ = '.';
        sum = 0;
      }
    }
  } while (ch);
}
```

By the way, [each "block" of the IPv4 address is an *octet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations), and what you are doing is replacing each with its [*digit sum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like homework (if this is the case, please tag it as `homework`), so I am going to give a few pointers:

- Use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html) to read the input from the user. Read the input into a string.
- Use [`sscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sscanf.html) to parse the string. Since you know there will be four positive integers, use `"%u.%u.%u.%u"` as the format string.
- For each one of the four integers, compute the sum of the digits (using division by 10 and remainder by 10, as you just did).
- Print the formatted output using `printf` (or [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/snprintf.html) to print to a string). If you want each sum to be formatted as a two-digits integer, with leading 0, use `"%02u"` as format specifier.

P.S. Be careful with `snprintf`, it might bite.

**Other tips**

Focus on one step at a time. *Divide and conquer*. Write a `digit_sum` function, taking an integer as argument, which computes the sum of its digits:

```
unsigned int digit_sum(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Once your `digit_sum` function is working well, proceed with the main task.

Comment: pizzalunga the above program i hv given is adding all digits in a[0] and thats the main problem....so kindly help me

Comment: Here is the full body of the `digit_sum` function.

Answer (score 1):

I just code you a simple example of how to "discard" unwanted characters.

```
#include <studio.h>

    main ()
    {
        int add1, add2, add3, add4;

        printf("enter an ip in the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: )";
        scanf("%d%*c%d%*c%d%*c%d", &add1, &add2, &add3, &add4);
        printf("add1 = %d add2 = %d add3 = %d add4 = %d\n\n", add1, add2, add3, add4);

        return 0;
    }
```

console output:

enter a ip in the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 123.321.456.654
add1 = 123 add2 = 321 add3 = 456 add4 = 654

EDIT: you just have to play along with the "add#" variables to do your math thing.